# Source not found for URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URL) line: not available error occurs if i start tomcat in myeclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

if i am  starting the tomcat or any one server for run the web application it give the error like  Source not found for URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URL) line: not available in myeclipse.

Comment: Are you starting Tomcat from myeclipse IDE?

Answer (score 3):

You're running Tomcat in debug mode and the Eclipse config/environment is a bit messed up.

To go around this, either don't run Tomcat in debug mode or clean up the Eclipse environment. Try restarting Eclipse with `-clean` argument. If in vain, try deleting (make backup!) the entire `.metadata` folder of the associated workspace and restart.